# Retrieve a list of folders in SharePoint using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I’m using the graph api from a c# app to access SharePoint. I need to get a list of all folders and sub folders. I have tried getting the drive item and then iterating through the children looking for folders and then recursively working through the list but it’s too slow.

I have also tried this end point

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/ContentType](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/ContentType) eq 'Folder'

With this header
Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

But it returned that the query would consume too many resources.

Is there a way to
A. Get the folders more efficiently or
B. Do a search to return folders or
C. Only list folders in the children endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can call this endpoint to get all files and folders in the specific library:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=driveItem
```

Comment: Trouble is there are thousands of items to go through and only relatively few folders. Is it possible to just list the folders instead of all the items

Comment: Yes, of course, you just need to do a simple filtering: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/lists/{list id}/items?$select=name,contentType,webUrl,id&$expand=driveItem,fields&$filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Folder'

Prefer: allowthrottleablequeries `

Comment: Im receiving the following exception, The Request is Unprocessable because it uses too many resources

Comment: It might be I need to create an index on the ContentType column?